# When moving email messages to other folders using an Outlook 2007 rule, I lose the messages in Gmail

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, gmail, rules

I use Gmail IMAP with Outlook 2007.

I created new folders under "inbox" in Outlook 2007 and set a rule for some of the incoming messages: when an email message arrives from a particular email address, the message will go directly to one of these subfolders.

It works great in Outlook but the messages are actually totally erased from the Gmail servers (I think; they are not in the Inbox when I check the Gmail web interface).

When using IMAP normally Gmail saves a copy in their servers too. Only when using subfolders and this rule it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you move your mails to subfolder of `[Gmail]` folder in Outlook? Gmail labels are shown as subfolders of `[Gmail]` folder in Outlook, so if you move your mails from `Inbox` to some other folder not under `[Gmail]` one, the message is deleted from `Inbox`.

Comment: ohh! i noticed that Gmail does show subfolders. i just refreshed the screen of the gmail web interface and noticed that the gmail updated itself and created the subfolders automatically and the emails are there ;) thanks.